# Cannot ping domains and ips from ubuntu server

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, ssh, vnc

I have a Ubuntu server which is running without any issues for the last one year.But now there is a wired issue caught my server and take server offline frequently.

I can connect server via VNC viewer but not with ssh and when I got logged in via vnc I cannot ping to outside world. 
From outside its is unreachable.

Do any one have any idea.Please help me.

Comment: Pease, provide us output from command `route -n`

Answer (score 1):

Could you run the following commands from VNC?

To understand why you can't connect to the outside world:

`ip a
ping 8.8.8.8
ping google.com`

To understand why VNC works and not SSH:

`ss -lt`